# Trouble with table: removing unwanted spaces between dt (with different sizes)

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the table in html.

I included within a  with the id #middlebody an Iframe that follows the form's size and a table which contains a single row, which has text and an input with an image on it.

```
    <div id='middlebody'>
<iframe src="" frameborder = 1 name="MrIframe"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
<table border = '3' cellspacing = "0">

<tr>
<td><b> INTERACTIVE DATABASE </b><br><a href='' target='MrIframe'><input type="image" src='Resources/Picture1.png' width=100 height =100 id ='interactive'></a></td>
<td><b> ADMINISTRATIVE PERFORMANCE </b><br><a href='' target='MrIframe'><input type="image" src='Resources/Picture6.png' width=100 height =100 id ='administrative'></a></td>
<td><b> ECONOMIC PERFORMANCE </b><br><a href='' target='MrIframe'><input type="image" src='Resources/Picture5.png' width=100 height =100 id ='economic'></a></td>
<td><b> SECTORAL PERFORMANCE </b><br><a href='' target='MrIframe'><input type="image" src='Resources/Picture2.png' width=100 height =100 id ='sectoral'></a></td>
<td><b> SOCIAL PERFORMANCE </b><br><a href='' target='MrIframe'><input type="image" src='Resources/Picture3.png' width=100 height =100 id ='social'></a></td>
<td><b> ENVIRONMENTAL PERFORMANCE </b><br><a href='' target='MrIframe'><input type="image" src='Resources/Picture4.png' width=100 height =100 id ='environmental'></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This is my CSS setup for my elements:

```
#middlebody
{
position: fixed;
left : 160px;
top: 80px;

display: block;
border: None;
width : 100%;
Height : 100%;

}

Iframe
{
display: block;
border: None;
width : 70%;
Height : 54%;
}


table 
{
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
td
{

    padding: 0;

    font-size: 100%;

text-align: center;
    }
```

If you are going to test my code, you will notice that there's still a margin between the items in my table items.

why is that? I've tried padding=0, border collapse, border spacing, but it doesn't seem to work

How can I make it so that the extra margin between cell items doesn't appear anymore, even when the text in it are of different lengths?

Any help is dearly appreciated.

**EDIT** here is a screenshot. What I would like is to remove the extra spaces between dt elements in the table.
[image: The bug]

Comment: I'm wondering why you doing it with table nod div?

Comment: it's a div, within it an iframe then the table

Comment: Could you do some jsfiddle?

Comment: I will do my best to generate one, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do u mean you have a margin? can you show us exactly what you need to remove? it is horizontal space or vertical space that you need to remove?

I think you set the width to 100% so the columns are divided upon the whole width of the screen, try to decrease the 100% to 80% then 60% and see how this affects the outcome

Comment: In short, I simply want the menu items(that are images) to fit inside the webpage. I'm looking to remove the horizontal spaces

Comment: I see what you mean. I simply changed the width of the #middlebody element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if you are up to this 
But I get codepen example for you -> [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/DcACh)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. You changed my width 100% to simply px.